# Show created field with only date in XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a custom XSL file I linked in one my view. I would like to display the created field value as a date only.

By now I have this xsl template :

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_ValueOf.Created"
            ddwrt:dvt_mode="body"
            ddwrt:ghost="">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode"
           select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name],1036,1)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, the format date method does not seems to be applied. What is missing in my template?

Please note I did not forget to add this xml namespace: `xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"`

**[Edit]**: I've changed a bit my template like this :

```
  <xsl:template name="FieldRef_ValueOf.Created"
                ddwrt:dvt_mode="body"
                ddwrt:ghost="">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode"
               select="."/>
    <span>here</span>
    <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]),1036,1)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Especially, I added a "span" just to check if it's taken into account. And it seems the "here" word does not appears. Actually, I don't think the problem is due to the date formatting, but the template itself.

Is there any restriction related to this oob column?

Comment: With this code what is the output? i mean the date format

Comment: @Diptarag: the output remains unchanged (no visible effect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is related with invoking template for a field, it means that in your case this template is not invoked at all.

In order to render field using your template the following attributes should be specified in template:

a) mode `DateTime_body`

b) match(*matches field by internal name in that case*)

```
    <xsl:template name="FieldRef_DateTime_body.Created" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" match="FieldRef[@Name='Created']" mode="DateTime_body" ddwrt:ghost="hide">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$FreeForm">
                <xsl:call-template name="FieldRef_ValueOf.Created">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                   </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                 <nobr>
                 <xsl:call-template name="FieldRef_ValueOf.Created">
                    <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </nobr>
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="FieldRef_ValueOf.Created"
                ddwrt:dvt_mode="body"
                ddwrt:ghost="">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode"
               select="."/>
    <span>here</span>
    <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]),1036,1)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

> Note: Your template is invoked as child template.

---

Actually there is a more simpler way how to achieve this

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_ValueOf.Created"
                match ="FieldRef[@Name='Created']" 
                mode="DateTime_body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode"
               select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string($thisNode/@Created),1036,1)" />
  </xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps,

Vadim

Comment: Your second suggestion is working exactly as expected. Thank you!

Comment: I had asked this question on Microsoft's Forums and the key for me was the mode attribute which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/7e4ed70d-2294-49be-9064-eb358a2b6336 .  When the XSLT is made in designer and embedded directly in the web part's XML you don't need the  mode however, in an external stylesheet you do.

Comment: About the usage of mode attribute, you right. Thanks!
Regarding documentation for mode attribute, you could find mapping information (mode <-> field type) in XSL file c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL\fldtypes.xsl. See template PrintField.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this on ContentQuery XSL ?
If so then Create outputs as a column "Created"

so in that case itwould be

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(Created), 1036, 1)" />
```

If you using a Dataview web part and that is the only way to get the date then you can try casting it to a string (I seem to recall that this needs to be passed as a string for the function to work (might be mistaken though)

In that case try this instead

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]),1036,1)"/>
```

Nothing to lose by trying anyway :)

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm customizing a list view in a webpart. Actually, my list schema defines a view where I put `        <XslLink Default="TRUE">some/path/myxsl.xsl</XslLink>`. In this XSL file, I've overwritten the global template to add a background color, and the template you saw in my question. As I state in my edit, I believe this is not the date formatting which is wrong, but the template selection.

Answer (score 0):

Add `xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal"` to the template node. So your template should now look like this:

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_ValueOf.Created"
                ddwrt:dvt_mode="body"
                ddwrt:ghost=""
                xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode"
               select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]),1036,1)"/>
</xsl:template>
```